# How to re-stream from Red5 to Wowza

Tags: flash, stream, red5, flash-media-server, wowza

I have trying to re-stream from Red5 to Wowza using Wowza Streamanager. This works great if I use FMS pulling stream into Wowza and to Flash players and IOS devices (if I use h.264/AAC on FMLE encoder - which works for both FMS and Red5).

I got it work when I pull from FMS 3.57, but if I change to pull from Red5 server (1.0) it fails and I see the follow error in console:

> INFO application app-start *definst* live/*definst*
>   INFO stream create - -
>   INFO server comment - LiveMediaStreamReceiver.connect: SSL:false url:rtmp://192.168.1.11:1935/live/*definst*/livestream
>   INFO server comment - HTTPStreamManager.onHTTPRequest: Publish stream successfully started [live/*definst*]: flv:rtmp.stream
>   ERROR server comment - handleResult[147]: can't find resultObj: 0 in 
>   WARN server comment - LiveMediaStreamReceiver.doWatchdog: streamTimeout[live/*definst*/livestream][1391201118701:1391201106675:12000]: Resetting connection: rtmp://192.168.1.11:1935/live/*definst*/livestream

Again the only thing I changed is pulling from FMS (which works) to Red5 (which does not). In both cases, if I got to Red5 or FMS, I can stream to simple Flash player, but I can not pull it from Wowza only FMS. - It seems Red5 response is different than FMS 3.57 - Any ideas?

Comment: Good guess - That is the issues - Both FMS and Wowza default to definst is none is given but not Red5. I had to add instance name to publishing stream than I was able to pull stream into Wowza - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

probably the reason is in auto app instance appending ("_definst_") of Wowza that is not supported by Red5.
that's just a wild guess..